# How to write functions like these intrinsic ones?

Tags: fortran

I just started to learn Fortran and I found that some intrinsic functions look mysteriously for me.
One of them is ALLOCATE: `ALLOCATE(array(-5:4, 1:10))`. If I want to write a similar function, how would it look? What is its argument? Which type it will have? Because it's not obvious to me what is `array(-5:4, 1:10)`? `array` still is not allocated, so what does this expression mean? What is its type?! What will be a difference in `array(10)` and `array(-5:4, 1:10)` as a type? Is it some hidden preallocated "meta-object" with some internal attribute like "dimension"? At least it does not look like array pointer in C.

And the next mysterious functions example is the PACK: `pack(m, m /= 0)`. First, I thought that `m /= 0` is like a function pointer, i.e. lambda, like in Python `pack(m, lambda el: el != 0)` or in Haskell `pack m (\el -> el /= 0)`. But then I read somewhere in the Web that it's not a lambda but a list of booleans, once per each `m` item. But this means that it's very inefficient code - it eats a lot of memory if `m` is big! So, I cannot understand how do these intrinsic functions work, even more, I have feeling that user cannot write such functions - they are coded in C and not in Fortran itself. Is it truth? How they were written?!

Comment: ALLOCATE is a statement, not a function; you can tell because it's NOT within an expression (or a CALL statement). PACK _is_ a function that acts _as if_ the mask (second argument) were fully created i.e. stored and then applied, but because it's intrinsic the compiler can optimize that away if it wants (often depending on options you select); you can't duplicate that even in C. You _can_ (in F90+) use a function pointer, but that will add cost to indirect each call which may well exceed the cost of storing the temporary array.

Comment: You need to read one (or more) tutorial on the Fortran language.  Several are available on the world-wide web.

Comment: so, is the next truth: semantically `m /= 0` is a list of booleans passed as an argument, but the compiler optimizes it to something as a lambda, it's a list only semantically, bit in the machine code it maybe something else without to consume so much memory? Is it right?

Comment: @evets yes, I read many, but I have background in other languages and I cannot read just plain Fortran without to ask myself - how does this relate to other language, how is this done... For example, when you see some library's function, you assume that an user is able to write similar, that no any magic here. This is the reason why I asked the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Allocate` is not a library function, as pointed out by @dave_thompson_085. Not only that, there are also some types of actual intrinsic functions that cannot be written by the user. Like `min()`, `max()`, `transfer()`. They are not just "library" functions, they are "intrisic", part of the core language and hence can do stuff that user code cannot. They are written in any language that was used to write the compiler. Mostly C, but could probably be also implemented in Fortran - just not like a normal Fortran function, but as a feature the compiler inserts.

When it comes to functions that accept a mask, like `PACK`, but there are many others that accept it in an optional argument, the mask is a `logical` array. The compiler is free to implement any optimizations to avoid allocating such an array, but these optimizations cannot be guaranteed. It is not just a library function that is called in a straightforward way, the compiler can insert any code that does what the function is supposed to do.